# Scrollbars not appearing when Silverlight app is minimized

Tags: silverlight

In our Silverlight app, when the user minimizes the screen, the right side gets cut off. THis is bad for us because we have 2 grids on right and left side with a pie in the middle.

How can we make this so that the entire page gets a horizontal and vertical bar in this instance. This also happens with older PC's but mostly the concern is where someone minimizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add scroll bars to your silverlight application, wrap the content in a ScrollViewer.  See below for example:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Name="SampleTextBlock" Text="This is my content" FontSize="72" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Be warned that grids might not behave correctly inside a `ScrollViewer`. Grids require there to be a known width to be able to size the columns correctly. A `ScrollViewer` effectively has infinite width so you might get all your columns bunched up to the left or spread out so far that the `ScrollViewer` is far too wide.